# decoder jpeg not available: django with apache2

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

when I try to use a simple code

```
        time_created = time.time()
        tempPath = 'user_image/'+ str(request.user.id)+'/'+str(time_created)+'/'
        print tempPath
        path = default_storage.save(tempPath+'original.jpg', ContentFile(content_image.read()))
        tmp_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path) #this line gives error
        image = open(tmp_file)
```

it gives me error : decoder jpeg not available

this is what I did to resolve it:
http://www.answermysearches.com/fixing-pil-ioerror-decoder-jpeg-not-available/320/

I am using python2.7
and Imaging-1.1.7

after following the above link, when i run python selftest.py on terminal, i get following output

```
python selftest.py
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 TEST SUMMARY 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from ./PIL
Binary modules loaded from ./PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok
*** TKINTER support not installed
--- JPEG support ok
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok
--- FREETYPE2 support ok
*** LITTLECMS support not installed
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Running selftest:
--- 57 tests passed.
```

But when I access my application from browser, I still get decoder jpeg not available

Note: I restarted apache server (not sure if its required).
Do I need to do some config changes in Apache?

I searched on stackoverflow, and found similar questions, but none was dealing with apache.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error. Reason was in other site run on server. It had old PIL in python path. So, cleaninig up python path or reinstallation of old PIL maybe can help you.